# Text coloring during search

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the color of the text according to the text the user searched for and ignore upper or lower case letters

The problem is that if the search text is not the same in terms of capital and small letters this code will not work.

I would appreciate help on how to improve the code in the best way so that I know how to do it for

Words with ignoring capital or small letters and put the word as it was in the `TextBlock` back.

Because I can just ignore uppercase or lowercase letters, but return the word like in search text

And not like in `TextBlock`

And I would also appreciate some general advice if this code can be improved.

`TextBox` is my search text and `TextBlock` is the text that I want to color part of

According to the search

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var searchText = (sender as TextBox)?.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) && TextBlock.Text.Contains(searchText))
    {
        var splitText = Regex.Split(TextBlock.Text, searchText);
        TextBlock.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = splitText[0] });

        for (var i = 1; i < splitText.Length; i++)
        {
            TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = searchText, Foreground = Brushes.Yellow });
            TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = splitText[i] });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string normalText = TextBlock.Inlines.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, line) => current + (line as Run)?.Text);
        TextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        TextBlock.Text = normalText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `TextBlock.Text.Contains(searchText)` use `TextBlock.Text.Contains(searchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` - if you are still on .net framework you need to use `TextBlock.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Comment: Contains with StringComparison overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-char-system-stringcomparison)

Comment: IndexOf with StringComparison overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-stringcomparison)

Comment: and ofcourse `Regex.Split` also has an option to ignore the case `Regex.Split("", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` : overload with RegexOptions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-split(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the casing in-tact of the orignal text, how about this

```
var input = "hElLo WoRlD";
var searchText = "llo";
var listSearchResults = new List<string>();

var currentPosition = 0;
while(true)
{
    var lastPosition = currentPosition;
    currentPosition = currentPosition >= input.Length ? -1 : input.IndexOf(searchText, currentPosition, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    if (currentPosition == -1)
    {
        if (listSearchResults.Count > 0)
            listSearchResults.Add(input.Substring(lastPosition));
            
        break;
    }
    
    listSearchResults.Add(input.Substring(lastPosition, currentPosition - lastPosition));
    listSearchResults.Add(input.Substring(currentPosition, searchText.Length));
    currentPosition += searchText.Length;
}

if (listSearchResults.Count > 0)
{
    //found
    //build run based on listSearchResults
    
    foreach (var item in listSearchResults)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/c3cOwR

Idea is to use `IndexOf` to move the position inside the original string, and use `Substring` on the orignal string to get the parts inside.

Edit:

To know which part of the list is the searchText you can simply do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < listSearchResults.Count; i++)
{
    var item = listSearchResults[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"{item} - {(i % 2 != 0)}");
}
```

The one returning TRUE on the `mod` operation `(i % 2 != 0)` will be the index with the searched text, as every second item in the list is the searchtext.

See it here in use:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PqHzms